# Hide empty fields from print view with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a form that requires printing. However, there might be fields that will be left blank and I would like them to be excluded from my print view altogether. I am talking about the JavaScript `window.print();` function and the print window that it opens.

Is there a way I can do something like this? Is there a way for me to handle logic in such events (ie. before print?).

Comment: instead of strictly using window.print(), can u add a customize function call such as function printScreen() { handleYourLogic(); window.print(); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS @media combined with some javascript to change the class dependent on whether the field is empty or not. Something like this...

```js
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
for(var i=0; i < fields.length; i++){
    fields[i].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
     if(this.value.length) {
         this.parentElement.className = "";
     } else {
       this.parentElement.className = "empty";   
     }
    });
}
```

```css
@media print {
    .empty {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="empty">Name: <input class="field"></div>
<div class="empty">Field: <input class="field"></div>
<div class="empty">Foo: <input class="field"></div>
```

(In the snippet, add something to a field but not all and then hit ctrl+p. you wont see the empty fields in the print preview)

If using jQuery you could cleanup the selectors and looping making the js something like this

```
$(".field").on("keyup", function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length) {
        $this.parent().removeClass("empty");
    } else {
        $this.parent().addClass("empty");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for the `window.print` event and use some jquery or javascript to check for empty inputs and hide them.

```
(function() {
    var beforePrint = function() {
        $('input').each(function(i,el){
          if($(el).val() == ''){
            $(el).hide();
          }
        });
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
      $('input').show();
    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

https://jsbin.com/gacikezulo/edit?html,js,console,output

Read this article [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/). But I took the combined script which should work in everything except Opera